# Why Swagger is not picking up the summary of an ApplicationService method in ABP Framework?

Tags: asp.net-core, swagger, abp

I have the following application service method.

```
public class MyAppService : AsyncCrudAppService<Entity, Dto, Guid, GetAllRequest, CreateRequest, UpdateRequest, GetRequest, DeleteRequest>, IMyAppService
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Return cities associated with zip code
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="zipCode">Zip code to search. If null all cities are returned.</param>
    /// <returns>Cities associated with zip code.</returns>
    /// <exception cref="EntityNotFoundException">If zip code is provided but no associated city is found</exception>
    /// <response code="404">If no city with zip code found</response>
    [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status200OK)]
    [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status404NotFound)]
    public async Task<GetCitiesByZipCodeResponse> GetCitiesByZipCode(int? zipCode = null)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Even though I have a summary describing what the endpoint does, it is not displayed in swagger. What is the right way to add rich information to Swagger about app service methods?

It did pick up the effect of `ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status404NotFound)` and showing 404 as possible response though.

[Swagger for GetCitiesByZipCode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tGr7s.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AppServices are automatically converted to Controllers. But your custom Swagger attributes are stripped off. If you have a such requirement, then create a new `MyContoller` and call your `AppService` methods inside the `Controller`. And disable remote service function for your `Appservice` with the following attribute

```
[RemoteService(IsEnabled = false)]
```

https://docs.abp.io/en/abp/latest/API/Auto-API-Controllers#remoteservice-attribute